# why is add skin data used in skin modifier? I found it always inactive

Tags: modifiers

we find an inactive button in skin modifier named add skin data what is it used for?[image: add skin data]

Answer (score 1):

It's used in a very specific cases when you change mesh data on object with Skin modifier (from dropdown if you select other mesh data in Data tab). Then you click this button so Skin modifier updates. Was added after this issue ([link](https://developer.blender.org/T44589)).